# Different syntax highlighting between specific tags in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working with Shopify code a lot at work, and I just started using VS Code to see if it's any good.

And I was hoping there may be an extension that allows different syntax highlighting between specific tags within a `*.liquid` file.

For example, Shopify has:

`{% schema %} JSON syntax highlighting {% endschema %}`

`{% javascript %} Javascript syntax highlighting {% endjavascript %}`

`{% stylesheet %} CSS/SCSS syntax highlighting {% endstylesheet %}`

Could something like this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done but no extension currently does it.

The built in [HTML extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/159fa624b2ef3d2b113cc9d23528af65068944c3/extensions/html/server/src) is a good example of switching between multiple language modes in a single file. It is somewhat complicated, but could definitely be done for liquid.